# Sonar-Runner multithreading?

Tags: sonarqube, code-metrics

I am using [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) for code quality control. The project analysis is performed by [sonar-runner](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyse+with+a+simple+Java+Runner). Right now, I cannot use the ant or maven tasks.

Problem: The analysis (sonar-runner) Java process is using only 4 processors, even though the machine has 8 processors.

Do you know of a way to configure the number of processors used?

Thanks!

Comment: This is still unsolved, and probably will remain so. Feel free to answer even if the question has aged for a bit. I'm still watching it.

Comment: AFAIK sonar analysis is mono threaded... I thin k there is room for improvement in terms of performances here ;) Anyway you should rather drop a mail to the sonar users mailing list

Comment: @Alexandre So it seems ... if you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in my previous comment: sonar analysis is mono threaded... I think there is room for improvement in terms of performances here. If this is an important issue for you, my advice would be to ask the sonar core team to make the sonar batch "multi threaded" using the sonar user mailing list.
Hope it helps